# Private chain: Extracting the "data" from an account?

Tags: transactions, web3js, private-blockchain, calldata

I have initiated and mined a transaction between two accounts. I also included a data field in this transaction. This is just random hex data. Here is the command:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[1],value:web3.toWei(1,"ether"),data:"4e4f"})
```

Now, from the transaction hash, I can get this data (It's in the input field):

```
eth.getTransaction("<transaction hash>")
{
  blockHash: "0xfa62730b0f9e310cd07d615b78857e338e845b9098c26f861e2713c5f690497d",
  blockNumber: 15,
  from: "0x37e5a459dbd48d4d9874e13cc334dab30373cece",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x2beef248d7d690d95cd1da22c8bf12937d323b197430e5a384cf4259db290bef",
  input: "0x4e4f",
  nonce: 2,
  to: "0xe1e09a6f9504d42e2e63e1b21447f4410159cf24",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 1000000000000000000
}
```

But, I want to retrieve this data using the **recipient** account address

> 0xe1e09a6f9504d42e2e63e1b21447f4410159cf24

We can get the balance of this account using **eth.getBalance(account_address)**. Along with the ether, I am also sending the data to this account (Is this not how it works?). So, is there an **eth.getData/eth.getInput** function similar to this to find the data received by an account?
Where is this data actually being stored in my private blockchain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data you're sending is part of the transaction, but it is not "added" to the account. There is storage associated with accounts (accessed via `eth.getStorageAt(address,location)`) but it will be empty unless a contract stores data there.

Since the data is associated only with the transaction, not with the account, the best way to access it is to use filters

```
var filter = eth.filter({fromBlock:0,toBlock:"latest", address:eth.accounts[1]});
var data = [];
filter.get(function(error,result){
    data.append(eth.getTransaction(result.transactionHash).data);
});

console.log(data)
```

Alternatively, you could create a contract that simply records all data sent to it:

```
contract Store {

    bytes[] public data;

    function(){
        data.push(msg.data);
    }
}
```

Then just fetch the data with `store.data(index);`

Comment: This line "var filter = eth.filter({fromBlock:0,toBlock:"latest", address:eth.accounts[1]);" maybe need a "}" no?