# Iterating over transactions in a private blockchain using web3.js

Tags: transactions, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain

This question is similar to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/iterating-over-all-public-values-of-a-mapping-in-web3) one. I'm trying to iterate through all transactions in a private block chain and look for specific data sent in the 'data' fields of each transactions. Is the following approach valid:

```
    // Fetch all transaction logs with the specified address
    filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', address: to_addr});
    // Get all entries
    results = filter.get((function(error, result){
          if (!error)
            console.log("[I] Fetched all transactions sent or sent to " + to_addr);
           else
            console.log("[E] An error has occurred " + error);
    });

    var json_tuple;
    // Iterate through the transactions in the logs 
    for(var log in results) {
        var log_tx_hash = log.transactionHash;
        // Lookup transaction with hash
        var tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(log_tx_hash);
        // Check the to and from addresses. We skip transactions unrelated to the current sender
        if(tx.from === from_addr) {
            // Parse transaction data and check recipient
            json_tuple = JSON.parse(tx.input);
            if(field in json_tuple) {
                //Do something with a field of the input data sent
                // as a JSON object
                console.log("We have found a transaction with data: " + json_tuple[[field]]);

            }
         }
    }
```

Is this a correct way of iterating through transactions based on a recipient address filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [Script to Find Transactions To/From an Account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/2460). You can just extract the data i.e., `input` fields from all the transactions.

Related:

[Listing transactions in a private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/listing-transactions-in-a-private-blockchain)

[Private chain: Extracting the “data” from an account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6394/private-chain-extracting-the-data-from-an-account)